# Get-BitlockerVolume Multiple factors for Uniqe row ID

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, formatting

I found this https://itpro.outsidesys.com/2017/10/21/powershell-change-values-in-csv-data/

I would like to use it to make a `CSV` that gets updated and does not have the same entry twice. 
`Get-BitlockerVolume` has no unique Row Data, so is there a way where I can use 2 Header/Row Datas to say This is ROW1 and this is ROW2 etc.

Like using the Date from the Header `ComputerName` and `Mountpoint` (Computername can come Multiple times due to the fact that some PC's have more then one Partition, MountPoint is the Drive letter and I would like to use this 2 Informations to identify the row.
Is this Possible?

```
#Get all AD Computers ATNB*
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "ATNB*"} | Select -Property Name
foreach ($pc in $cn.name){

#Test connection
        $connection = test-connection -buffersize 32 -count 1 -ComputerName $pc -quiet

    if ($connection -eq $True) {
            #Run command on pc esport to csv add new row
            invoke-command -computername $cn.name -scriptblock {get-bitlockervolume} | export-csv -Append "C:\_test\New folder\bitlockercheck.csv"
            echo "$pc Info added to CSV"
    }
    else {echo "$pc is not online"}
}
```

this is the new/updated script:

```
$csv = @(Import-Csv "C:\_test\New folder\bvt_2.csv")

#Get all AD Computers ATNB* and start looping
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "ATNB*" } | ForEach-Object {
    # Assign the "Name" value of the current computer to $pc
    $pc = $_.Name

    # Test connection
    if (Test-Connection -buffersize 32 -count 1 -ComputerName $pc -quiet) {
        #Run command on pc esport to csv add new row
        Invoke-Command -Computername $pc -scriptblock { Get-BitlockerVolume } | ForEach-Object {
            # For each bit locker volume...
            $volume = $_

            # ... see if a row exists for the volume
            $csvRow = $csv | Where-Object { $_.ComputerName -eq $pc -and $_.MountPoint -eq $volume.MountPoint }

            # if a row exists, update the Data column only
            if ($csvRow) {
                $csvRow.Data = $volume.Data
                echo "$pc Info updated in CSV"
            } else {
                # Otherwise add a new row to the CSV
                $csv += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $pc
                    MountPoint   = $volume.MountPoint
                    Data         = $volume.Data
                }
                echo "$pc Info added to CSV"
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$pc is not online"
    }
}

# Export the updated CSV file
$csv | Export-Csv "C:\_test\New folder\bvt_2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Can you please add your Powershell code so far?

Comment: I added my code so far... It is okay for a 1 Time run. After the first run It would just add doubles all the time...So I am looking for a way to Identify the rows and Compare them to the new Output wich I get from Get-BitlockerVolume

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `PSComputerName` available as an extra property when you use `Invoke-Command`, you can use that as a unique key.

When you can reach a computer and list its BitLockerVolumes, you get a complete list. You basically want to remove *all* the volumes of that computer from the CSV file and add the new list.

Now what I would do is

- collect all BitLockerVolume objects from all online computers
- make a unique array of strings from PSComputerName
- import the cached CSV file, filtering out all objects that have their computername in this array
- make a new list from cached data + current data and overwrite the CSV file

So, along the lines of this:

```
$CSV_PATH = "C:\_test\New folder\bitlockercheck.csv"

$current_data = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "ATNB*"' | Foreach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection $_.Name -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {Get-BitLockerVolume}
    }
}

$computernames = $current_data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSComputerName -Unique

$cached_data = Import-Csv $CSV_PATH | Where-Object {
    -not ($computernames -contains $_.PSComputerName)
}

$cached_data + $current_data | Export-Csv $CSV_PATH
```

You absolutely should do the filtering on the AD server. The way you currently do it, you download *all* AD computers to your machine first and throw most of them away immediately. By passing a filter string to `Get-ADComputer` you will only get those objects you are interested in, which is much more efficient.

Comment: I have Asked some people from an IRC where I've got some help before. I added the "new" script, which looks more logical.

Comment: Maybe you should continue getting help on IRC then.